# Parsing namespace xml generates AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

The following code causes this error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'" Can some show me how to fix this error. This error is cause by value.text = str(ImageState)

```
for ecu_container in root.findall('.//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE'):
    short_name = ecu_container.find('.//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}SHORT-NAME').text
    if(short_name == component):
        value = ecu_container.find('.//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}VALUE').text
        value.text = str(imageState)
```

Comment: value is already the text attribute of your target element. delete the `.text` of the first line, it should be ok

Answer (score 1):

I have found my problem. The command
value = ecu_container.find('.//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}VALUE').text is incorrect. It should be
value = ecu_container.find('.//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}VALUE').

I had added .text to this line to read the data to ensure I was getting the correct data to update but never removed the .text when trying to write the data.